# Problems inheriting properties from a supertype

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I'm creating an `Animal` supertype constructor which has a method that should be available for all 'bird' and 'cat' objects.

- How should I add this prototype to make sure I don't overwrite the subtypes' prototype?
- Can I use a subtype prototype's variable in the supertype prototype?

**Example**

```js
function Animal() { }

Animal.prototype = {
  constructor: Animal,
  say: function(sound) {
    console.log(`${sound}`);
  }
};

function Cat(name) {
  this.name=name
 }
function Bird(name) {
  this.name=name
 }
Cat.prototype = {
  constructor:Bird,
  sound:'meow'
}
Bird.prototype = {
  constructor:Bird,
  sound:'Bach Op1 D minor'
}

Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)
Bird.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)
//is this overwriting the prototype already set?
let myCat = new Cat("rupert")
console.log(myCat.name, myCat.say(), Cat.prototype)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using this syntax over [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)?

Comment: Just start playing and notice some knowledge gap and ended up here. Indeed, Classes seems to be way easier and more readable @Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign` to inherit from Animal's prototype but also be able to add your own fields and methods. Also, you need to use `this.sound` to access the property of the instance itself.

```
Animal.prototype = {
  constructor: Animal,
  say: function() {
    console.log(`${this.sound}`);
  }
};
//...
Cat.prototype = Object.assign(Object.create(Animal.prototype), {
  constructor:Bird,
  sound:'meow'
});
Bird.prototype = Object.assign(Object.create(Animal.prototype),{
  constructor:Bird,
  sound:'Bach Op1 D minor'
});
```

Demo:

```js
function Animal() { }

Animal.prototype = {
  constructor: Animal,
  say: function() {
    console.log(`${this.sound}`);
  }
};

function Cat(name) {
  this.name=name
 }
function Bird(name) {
  this.name=name
 }
Cat.prototype = Object.assign(Object.create(Animal.prototype), {
  constructor:Bird,
  sound:'meow'
});
Bird.prototype = Object.assign(Object.create(Animal.prototype),{
  constructor:Bird,
  sound:'Bach Op1 D minor'
});
//is this overwriting the prototype already set?
let myCat = new Cat("rupert")
console.log(myCat.name, myCat.say(), Cat.prototype)
```

Comment: Amazing. But in the code snipped the call to 'say' is yet returning `undefined`?

Comment: @misternobody You did not return anything from the function. You are only calling `console.log`, which is why it implicitly returns `undefined`.

Comment: uhu? I'm confused here I believe there should be some sound output anyways

Comment: @misternobody Then write `return this.sound` instead of `console.log(this.sound)`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didnt see the word meow in the first line. Thanks!

Comment: @misternobody No problem.